# Estimate the propotion of Republicans in a certain district

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Hoel's Probability Book Problem Chapter 3: If you wished to estimate the propotion of Republicans in a certain district and wanted your estimate to be correct withing .02 unit with a probability of .90, how large a sample should you take (a) if you know the true proportion is near0.4 (b) if you have no idead what the true propotion is?
my solution to (a)
Let $p=0.9$, $q=0.1$ $\sigma=3$, then
$$p+3\sqrt{\frac{pq}{n}}=0.03$$
$$0.9+3\sqrt{\frac{0.9\times0.1}{n}}=0.03$$
$$3\sqrt{\frac{0.9\times0.1}{n}}=-0.87=\sqrt{\frac{0.9\times0.1}{n}}=-0.29$$
$$\frac{0.9\times0.1}{n}=0.0841$$
n=1.0702

Can you please help me with (a) and (b)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing notation slightly, but in general you're on the right track.

If you measure a proportion $\hat{p}$ out of a sample of size $n$, the confidence interval  of the true proportion $p$ is given by
$$ \hat{p} \pm z \sqrt{\frac{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})}{n}},$$
where $z$ is the appropriate quantile of the standard normal distribution.

You should interpret the question as: what $n$ do you need in order for the confidence interval to have a total length of $0.02$?

First, observe that $z = 1.65$ in our case, because $\Pr(-1.65 <Z < 1.65) \approx 0.9$, which is the level of precision we desire. (You can verify this in a $Z\text{-score}$ lookup table.)

Furthermore, because the total length of the interval (both plus and minus) should be $0.02$, we need that
$$  z \sqrt{\frac{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})}{n}} = 0.01.$$

Now if we know that $\hat{p}$ will be approximately $0.4$, we can substitute to obtain

$$1.65\sqrt{\frac{(0.4)(0.6)}{n}}=0.01,$$
which, if you solve for $n$, yields $n=6534$. (part a)

So you need a sample size of $6534$ in order for the confidence interval to be about $0.02$ wide, if you know that the real probability is somewhere around $0.4$.

However, if you have no clue about the real probability, then you should assume a probability of $0.5$ (this is called the distribution with *maximum entropy*). Then, you can subsitute again, to obtain
$$1.65\sqrt{\frac{(0.5)(0.5)}{n}}=0.01,$$
which yields $n = 6807$. (part b)

Comment: Good answer, but I interpreted "having no idea about the true proportion" as having a uniform distribution over the proportion *p*, rather than picking a single value of *p* =0.5. In virtually all cases, the true proportion, whatever it is, will carry less entropy than *p* =0.5, so you'll have sampled more than you needed to. You'll need 6807 samples *if* the true proportion is 0.5, but since it's almost certainly not, you don't need that many samples most of the time.

Comment: I would interpret it as: what sample size would *guarantee* that I have a confidence interval no bigger than $0.02$? (Of course, smaller is always acceptable.) That is the case if $n$ is at least $6807$, without any assumptions on what $\hat{p}$ actually is.

Comment: But we want a confidence interval of width 0.02 to contain the true proportion 90% of the time. If you run this many times in populations with different true proportions, a confidence interval with a width of 0.02 will contain the true proportion *more* than 90% of the time. We're not looking for a guarantee that the 90% CI has a width of 0.02 or less, we just need that to be the case on average.

Comment: Good point. Interesting question, any ideas how to work that out analytically? I reckon something with integrating over the total set of possible $p$'s.

Comment: Something like finding $n$ such that $\int^1_0 1.65\sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}}\,dp = 0.01$? That would yield $n = 4199$.

Comment: Right, it'll involve some kind of integration over *p* from 0 to 1. The value of 4199 is also the solution if p=0.25 or 0.75, which are values of "average entropy" assuming uniform distribution over *p*. Looks right to me.